# how to trigger next tab with <a> or <button> element in materialize

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

```
<div class="col s12">
  <ul class="tabs">
   <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#test1"  class="active">tab1</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#test2">tab2</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#test4">tab3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id='test1' class="col s12">
   <a href='#test2' >continue</a>
</div>
<div id='test2' class="col s12"></div>
```

i am trying to navigate to next tab [image]after clicking on the button or link such as "Continue Button" in materializeCss. I have attached the image for better understanding.

Comment: Write your code on `.click()` event?

Comment: can you show how because i tried  several things

Answer (score 7):

Refer to document of `Materialize`

http://materializecss.com/tabs.html

Write your code on `.click()` event, as following.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.tabs').tabs();
  $("#btnContinue").click(function() {
    $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', 'test2');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="col s12">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#test1" class="active">tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#test2">tab2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#test4">tab3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id='test1' class="col s12">
  <a id="btnContinue" href='#test2'>continue</a>
</div>
<div id='test2' class="col s12"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
  $("#btnContinue").click(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("tabs");
    var instance = M.Tabs.getInstance(el);
    instance.select('test2');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't work for the Jquery and materialize version mentioned below. Instead of "select_tab" method, we need to call "select" method here ( probable select_tab is deprecated )

The below code works for JQuery v3.2.1 and Materialize v1.00-rc.2

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul.tabs').tabs();
        $('#btnContinue').click(function(){
            $('ul.tabs').tabs("select", "tab2");
        });     
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The below works, though I noticed it may be slightly delayed as it goes through the entire document. It uses a [wildcard selector](http://thea.li/css3-wildcard-selectors) (*) and that can be changed to (^) -- will match if the attribute begins with the given string (think class prefixes).

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href*="#"]', function() {
    $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', this.hash.slice(1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Reload() {
  window.location.reload(true);
}
       
document.getElementById("reload-button").onclick = function () {
  setTimeout(Reload, 100);
};
```

```html
<a id='reload-button' href='next-tab'>button</a>
```