# How to move to next/previous tab with materialize css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

in materialize we can select tab with jquery code like $('.tabs').tabs('select', 'tabid') but the question is how to move to next or previous tab when i click the "button" tag?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12 l12">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3" data-tab="tab1"><a href="#data_siswa">Data Siswa</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3" data-tab="tab2"><a href="#data_ortu">Data Orang Tua</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3" data-tab="tab3"><a href="#document">Document</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3" data-tab="tab3"><a href="#pilih_jurusan">Pilih Jurusan</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="data_siswa" class="col s12">
    <button type="button" class="btn">Next</button> 
</div>
<div id="data_ortu" class="col s12">
    <button type="button" class="btn">Previous</button> 
    <button type="button" class="btn">Next</button> 
</div>
<div id="document" class="col s12">
    <button type="button" class="btn">Previous</button> 
    <button type="button" class="btn">Next</button> 
</div>
<div id="pilih_jurusan" class="col s12">
    <button type="button" class="btn">Previous</button> 
    <button type="button" class="btn">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456557/how-to-trigger-next-tab-with-a-or-button-element-in-materialize

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to trigger next tab with <a> or <button> element in materialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456557/how-to-trigger-next-tab-with-a-or-button-element-in-materialize)